# Django - Multiple instance of same model in single form

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to display multiple instance of same object in a form and collect all the data in single click. One example I can think of is let say, I want to take attendance of fifty students in my db. I need to present the user with all the students and a check box so as to mark, who all are present and submit the result at end.

Note: I am fairly new to Django, I am okay with models and forms as a beginner.

Comment: you can use: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/